# Spring expression parsing using evaluation context for boolean field

Tags: java, boolean, pojo, spring-el

I am using spring-expression for parsing  values in a class(present in jar). After i read this value i set it in the target class [a typical use case of spring-expression]. However, all the field's value from the class in jar can be parsed except, boolean value. In the source class, it is declared like this:

```
boolean isVerified;

//getter
public isVerified() {
  return isVerfied;
}
```

Spring-expression code to read this value:

```
Expression sourceExp = parser.parseExpression(<source field string>);
sourceExp.getValue(sourceContext);
```

and this fails. The message is 
Couldn't find property isVerified

My question is it because spring is looking for isIsVerified method rather than isVerified method? If not this what could be the reason for failure?

Comment: Have you already tried to use `boolean verified;`?

Comment: I can not, since the jar (having the class) is provided to me by a different team and I can not modify that jar

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your expression but SpEL uses JavaBean semantics when accessing bean properties. It knows nothing about the internals of the referenced bean. When it encounters a property request...

```
"x.foo"
```

it tries to find the getter `getFoo()` (any return type) and if that's not found, it looks for `isFoo()` if it returns boolean.

I suspect you are trying to use `x.isVerified`. There is no such getter; you need to use `x.verified`, or you can invoke the method itself `x.isVerified()`.

Comment: yes. as mentioned in the problem the field name is isVerified ; So do i need to use x.isIsVerified() for this case?

Comment: The field name is irrelevant; SpEL uses the getter. So you either need `x.verified` or `x.isVerified()`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/support/ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java#L349